# jsonRPCClient Error with php variables

Tags: php, json, function, variables, bitcoin

am trying to run the following code

```
$betamount=$_POST['bet']; 
$litecoin->move($myusername,Admin,$betamount);
```

but it will not work. it does however work when i replace $betamount with an actual number ie

```
$litecoin->move($myusername,Admin,0.2);
```

or

```
$betamount=0.1; 
$litecoin->move($myusername,Admin,$betamount);
```

any ideas on whats going wrong ? the $_POST['bet'] is defiantly a number because i have tried multiplying in php and it all works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this now, All you have to do is change it to this

```
floatval(trim()) ie ...    $betamount=floatval(trim($_POST['bet']));
```

for numbers

and this

```
 trim()  ie ... $litecoinaddr=trim($_POST['address']);
```

for strings